# What program can i use to create something similar to these charts

Tags: math-software

[image][image]

I'm using matlab and never see something similar,  i saw this in a recent paper and wondering what software is used

Comment: One way to do this is with [TikZ in LaTeX](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/PGF/TikZ).

Comment: Or *Mathematica*.